# I don't understand why logic isn't working as expected

Tags: java, logic, if-statement

I am creating a method where I must decide in which I am depending on hour of the day by using simple `else` / `else if` / `else` statements.

I don't understand why program is going straight to the `else` section.

What is wrong with my logic? I know this question is embracing to ask, but I'm so confused and I really want to know what is wrong here.

```
public String whichClass()
{
    String string = "";
    int ClassLength = 2;

    this.setLengthOfOS(ClassLength);
    this.setLengthOfSecurity(ClassLength);
    this.setLengthOfForensics(ClassLength);

    this.setOSStartHour(13);
    this.setSecurityStartHour(15);
    this.setForensicsStartHour(17);

    Date d = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    c.setTime(d);

    this.setHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

    if ((this.getHour() > this.getOSStartHour()) && 
            (this.getHour() < this.getSecurityStartHour())) 
    { 
        string = "We're in OS class."; 
    }
    else if ((this.getHour() > this.getSecurityStartHour()) && 
            (this.getHour() < this.getForensicsStartHour()))
    { 
        string = "We're in Security class."; 
    }
    else 
    {
        string = "We have no class.";
    }

    return string;
}
```

**EDIT: This is corrected and working.**

```
public String whichClass()
{
    String string = "";
    Date d = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
    this.setHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

    if ((this.getHour() >= this.OSStartHour) && (this.getHour() < (this.OSStartHour + this.lengthOfOS))) string = "We're in OS class."; 
    else if ((this.getHour() >= this.SecurityStartHour) && (this.getHour() < (this.SecurityStartHour + this.lengthOfSecurity))) string = "We're in Security class."; 
    else if ((this.getHour() >= this.ForensicsStartHour) && (this.getHour() < (this.ForensicsStartHour + this.lengthOfForensics))) string = "We're in Security class."; 
    else string = "We have no class.";

    return string;
}
```

Comment: debug/print your variables (for your own benefit).

Comment: you can do some quick debugging by printing the results of `this.getHour()`, and see if that's wrong.   Also, what ever happened to forensics class?

Comment: I have, all variables are correctly set. I have double checked that.

Comment: What time was it when you ran the program?

Comment: Well since they're returning false when you're expecting them to return true there must be something off with the numbers and/or the statements.

Comment: well then, what is `this.getHour()` returning then?

Comment: Pull out the part that creates a new Date, and create a method that takes the current date as a parameter. Now you have a method you can write a test for. You can start plugging in values, adding assertions, and solve this for yourself.

Comment: `this.getHour()` returns 15 at this moment since it's 3 PM. Soon will be 16.

Comment: also, you don't need so many parenthesis.  If you'd count on your order of operations just a little bit more, your conditions would be easier to read

Comment: Well, if it is 15 it is exactly the same as `this.getSecurityStartHour()`, so none of the `if` checks will yield true.

Comment: @Nathan Hughes, you are partly right, If i would count the entire time it would work, but since I am using only hour of the day it causes problems.

Comment: Two thoughts:  Write a unit test and externalize how you're getting the current time so you can test independent of the system clock.

Comment: you shouldn't feel embarrassed by this by the way.  none of us realized what the problem was either until we had a solid example to latch onto

Comment: Sam I am has a point. that is why people write tests, so you get that working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're not accounting for equality.  So  when `this.getHour()` is 15, then it won't fall into any slot.

both
`this.getHour() < this.getSecurityStartHour()` is false
and
 `this.getHour() < this.getSecurityStartHour()` is false,

because they're both strict inequalities

`this.getHour() == this.getSecurityStartHour()` is true

try

```
if ((this.getHour() >= this.getOSStartHour()) && 
        (this.getHour() < this.getSecurityStartHour())) 
{ 
    string = "We're in OS class."; 
}
else if ((this.getHour() >= this.getSecurityStartHour()) && 
        (this.getHour() < this.getForensicsStartHour()))
{ 
    string = "We're in Security class."; 
}
else 
{
    string = "We have no class.";
}
```

take note of teh **>=** instead of the **>**

Answer (score 2):

This is mathematic question:

this.getOSStartHour() = 13

this.getSecurityStartHour() = 15

this.getForensicsStartHour() = 17

So only for hour = 14 we can reach first if

For hour = 16 we can reach second if

For rest else

Answer (score 2):

Your code is running the `else` part because the `Calendar`s hour of day is neither `14` (`"OS class"`) nor `16` (`"Security class"`).

If you change your system clock to, say, `14`, it should print `"We're in OS class."`. By the same token, if you change it to `16`, it should print `"We're in Security class."`.

Also note that if you change it to `15`, it will always execute the `else` part. That's because you only consider `hour > 13 and hour < 15`, and `hour > 15 and hour < 17`, but not `hour >= 15` or `hour <= 15`. Don't know if it's an error, or desired behaviour.

Comment: I am passing only hour of the day. Not the time with minutes.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: Yes, it was just to exemplify, it doesn't really matter here. I've edited my answer to avoid confusions though.

Answer (score 2):

> this.getHour() returns 15 at this moment since it's 3 PM. Soon will be 16

Because none of your conditions allow for equality (`>=`,`<=`,`==`) the hours `13`, `15`, and `17` are essentially taboo. So your program is expected only to work when hour is `14` or `16`.